Possibility of Adding Ciphertexts encrypted by different public keys in the RLWE FHE scheme
Assume we use RLWE encryption scheme to encrypt one message $\hat m$;
Basic Concepts of RLWE encryption scheme:
$\quad$ secret key $sk=\hat s \in A_{N,q}$
$\quad$ public key $pk=(\hat{u_0}\cdot \hat s +\hat{e_0},\hat{u_0}) $ where $ \hat{u_0}\in A_{N,q}$
$\quad$ Homomorphic encryption operation with public key $pk$ and plaintext $\hat m$: $Enc(\hat m, pk)$
$\quad$ Homomorphic decryption operation with secret key $sk$ and ciphertext $c$: $Dec(c, sk)$
Given two public-private key pairs $pk_1, sk_1$ &  $pk_2,sk_2$ and following steps:
Step1: Encrypt $\hat m$ into ciphertext $c_1$: $c_1=Enc(\hat m, pk_1)$
Step2: Encrypt 0 into ciphertext $c_2$: $c_2=Enc(0, pk_2)$
Step3: Homomorphic Add $c_1 c_2$ and produce $c_3$
Step4: Using $sk_1$ to decrypt $c_3$ into ciphertext $c_4$: $c_4=Dec(c_3, sk_1)$
I have two main questions:

Is Step3 described above achievable?
If Step3 is achievable, can $c_4$ be security and $Dec(c_4, sk_2)=\hat m$ ?

